# Trying to replicate JavaScript hashes on C#

Tags: c#, javascript, hash

I am trying to replicate a JavaScript hash on C#, but I am getting a different result.
The code on JavaScript is:

```
var key = "35353535353535366363636363",
credentials = "web:web",  
shaObj = new jsSHA(credentials, "ASCII"), 
hash = shaObj.getHMAC(key, "HEX", "SHA-1", "HEX"); // key and generated hash are hex values
alert("Hash: " + hash);
```

it returns the following hash:

```
60c9059c9be9bcd092e00eb7f03492fa3259f459
```

The C# code that I am trying is:

```
key = "35353535353535366363636363";
string credentials = "web:web";

var encodingCred = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
var encodingKey = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] keyByte = encodingKey.GetBytes(key);
byte[] credentialsBytes = encodingCred.GetBytes(credentials);
using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte))
{
    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(credentialsBytes);
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashmessage).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
    Console.WriteLine("HASH: " + hash);              
}
```

it returns the following hash:

```
5f7d27b9b3ddee33f85f0f0d8df03540d9cdd48b
```

I suspect the issue may be that I am passing the 'key' as ASCII instead of HEX. After many hours of research I haven't been able to figure out the necessary changes to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want different hashing functions to return the same thing?

Comment: @Magus Different APIs, but same function: HMAC-SHA1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he answered the question in the question. Different inputs shouldn't give the same output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in how the `key`s are being converted to "*bytes*."

The JavaScript snippet is parsing the `String` as `"HEX"`, which should result in:

```
[ 0x35, 0x35, ..., 0x36, ... ]
```

While the C# snippet is just grabbing the ASCII values of each `Char` in the `String`, resulting in:

```
{ 0x33, 0x35, 0x33, 0x35, ..., 0x33, 0x36, ... }
// "3" => U+0033
// "5" => U+0035
// "6" => U+0036
```

To match, the C# version will need to parse the `String` as hex as well. One way of doing that is with [`StringToByteArray()`, as defined in another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/15031):

```
// ...
byte[] keyByte = StringToByteArray(key);
// ...
```

```
60c9059c9be9bcd092e00eb7f03492fa3259f459
```